# Unity - populate inspector with different values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

I have the following collection in C# which is sent to Google servers (Firebase Remote Config).

I want to add values in the Unity inspector itself and not in code. As you can see, the values can be any type (bool, string, int, etc).

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> defaults =
            new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();

        defaults.Add("config_test_string", "default local string");
        defaults.Add("config_test_int", 1);
        defaults.Add("config_test_float", 1.0);
        defaults.Add("config_test_bool", false);
```

Basically I've done this:

```
[Serializable]
    public struct RemoteValueConfig {
        public string key;
        public object defaultValue;
    }



    public RemoteValueConfig[] valuesToFetch;
```

But it doesn't work, since the "object" type won't show up in the Unity inspector. If I only needed string objects, I would simply replace `defaultValue` which is of type object, with a string type and this would solve my problem. But I can have int's, float's, strings, bool, etc.

How can I populate values in this scenario (and what to use), to work with Unity inspector?

Answer (score 1):

Unity's inspector doesn't support generics, so the answer is a little more complex than what you'd normally do in C#.  But, according to Unity's answer community, you can provide concrete implementations of a shared base class to get around this limitation:

EDIT: Changed these from structs to classes and added the default constructors in the subclasses to make it compilable

```
[Serializable]
public class RemoteValueConfigBase<T>
{
    public string Key;
    public T DefaultValue;

    public RemoteValueConfigBase(string key, T defaultValue)
    {
        Key = key;
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class RemoteValueConfigStr : RemoteValueConfigBase<string>
{
    public RemoteValueConfigStr(string key, string defaultValue) : base(key, defaultValue)
    { }
}

[Serializable]
public class RemoteValueConfigBool : RemoteValueConfigBase<bool>
{
    public RemoteValueConfigBool(string key, bool defaultValue) : base(key, defaultValue)
    { }
}

[Serializable]
public class RemoteValueConfigInt : RemoteValueConfigBase<int>
{
    public RemoteValueConfigInt(string key, int defaultValue) : base(key, defaultValue)
    { }
}

[Serializable]
public class RemoteValueConfigDouble : RemoteValueConfigBase<double>
{
    public RemoteValueConfigDouble(string key, double defaultValue) : base(key, defaultValue)
    { }
}

...etc
```

Then your collection of defaults would be able to be this:

EDIT: Note I changed it from a dictionary to a list because your object that you provided was already a key/value format - but this answer is meant to point you in the right direction as I'm unsure exactly how you intend to use it.  The base classing still is the same.

```
var defaults = new List<RemoteValueConfigBase<object>();
defaults.Add(new RemoteValueConfigStr("config_test_string", "default local string"));
defaults.Add(new RemoteValueConfigInt("config_test_int", 1));
defaults.Add(new RemoteValueConfigDouble("config_test_float", 1.0));
defaults.Add(new RemoteValueConfigBool("config_test_bool", false));
```

For more details check out [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/214300/serializable-class-using-generics.html) link

Comment: Oh for duck's sake, why didn't I think of generics when doing the thing I did (see my answer). Well, at least it's refactorable.

Comment: hm, interesting. I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Draco18s haha I'm actually not familiar with Unity so my first instinct was 'just make your type generic' - but once I googled a bit I realized you couldn't serialize generics in Unity so this was my middle route

Comment: @RobertPetz I meant more in terms of "why didn't I think of that"? I know what generics *are* and I've created generic classes before, but for that project I just...didn't...for some reason.

Comment: Also gonna update my answer a bit as right now that doesn't compile -
 @Draco18s gotcha haha

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to make a "wrapper object" that does get displayed in the inspector (you will also need [a custom inspector script](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector) for it).

For example, in a idle-clicker game I'm working on, I have [this](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/upgrades/Upgrade.cs#L69-L85) set up to handle the different value types an upgrade can have (float or integer):

```
public abstract class UpgradeValueWrapper { }

public class UpgradeIntValue : UpgradeValueWrapper {
    public int value;
    public UpgradeIntValue(int v) {
        value = v;
    }
}

public class UpgradeFloatValue : UpgradeValueWrapper {
    public float value;
    public UpgradeFloatValue(float v) {
        value = v;
    }
}
```

Your dictionary would then be `<string,AbstractWrapper>` with a custom inspector script that handles the translation for display.  By declaring the type as being something more specific than `object` (which could literally be anything) that has a known number of subtypes that wrap around the values you want, it becomes a lot easier to insure that the data is something that can be handled.

I don't know if it would actually *work,* I've only built one or two inspector scripts and I always came away from it thinking "ugh, I don't ever want to do that again." A custom inspector script *by itself* might also be enough, but I don't know if trying to write one for `object` would work; I suspect not.